# How to add column to if not exist and update value

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have this script

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].TableName ADD ColumnName BIT DEFAULT(1)
GO
UPDATE [dbo].TableName SET ColumnName = 1
```

I have to add condition to check is column already exist, but then there is error with `go`

This script is also not working

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
          WHERE Name = N'ColumnName'
          AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'dbo.TableName'))
BEGIN

    ALTER TABLE [dbo].TableName ADD ColumnName BIT DEFAULT(1)
    UPDATE [dbo].TableName SET ColumnName = 1   

END
```

There must be `IF` condition. How to fix that?

Comment: What is not working about your stored procedure?

Comment: Note: for a large table (large as in a million rows or more), there's a better approach: Instead of adding a nullable column with with a default value and updating the table, you can add a non-nullable column with the default value, and then alter it to a nullable column. For details, read [this SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30356453/time-to-add-default-values-to-a-new-column-by-approach/30357178#30357178)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `IF EXISTS` should be an `IF NOT EXISTS`. More importantly, you need to execute the `ALTER` and the `UPDATE` separately, like so:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
          WHERE Name = N'ColumnName'
          AND Object_ID = Object_ID(N'dbo.TableName'))
BEGIN

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'ALTER TABLE [dbo].TableName ADD ColumnName BIT DEFAULT(1)';
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].TableName SET ColumnName = 1'; 

END
```

Comment: No need for a different scope, a simple `;` after the `alter` statement will suffice.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, a simple `;` after the `alter` still gives me `Invalid column name 'ColumnName'.`

Comment: @ZoharPeled in rextester it also works without `;`, might be something to do with the web implementation. On my local installation it doesn't work.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Don't know what to say, it doesn't work for me. Does it also work with the `IF` and `BEGIN...END`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled I don't understand, I'll try again later. I try to stay away from my computer in the weekends.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, Well, it definitely doesn't work when I try. I keep getting Invalid column name.

Comment: It might be a version issue or something. Rextester are working with 2014 and I tested on 2016.

Comment: I'm also on 2016.

Answer (score 0):

You should check with `IF NOT EXISTS`, you are missing the `NOT`.

And I expect you want to `UPDATE` the column outside the `IF` statement, because it won't do anything on a new column with that same default value.

The `Go` statement is used to split one request into multiple smaller requests. That is why you cannot split within an `IF` statement.

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.columns 
              WHERE Name = N'ColumnName'
               AND  Object_ID = Object_ID(N'dbo.TableName'))
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].TableName ADD ColumnName BIT DEFAULT(1)
END

GO
UPDATE [dbo].TableName SET ColumnName = 1
```